# If there is no oxygen in space what does the sunshine burn for fuel?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, vacuum, sun, combustion

Since there is no oxygen in space how does the sun burn fuel?

Comment: Welcome to SE! :-) As the answer by @gryphys tells you, the Sun is not "a fire" and therefore does not need oxygen. But still, just because there is no oxygen in the interstellar space, why does would that mean that there cannot be oxygen in the Sun? In general, there $\textit{are}$ other elements outside of the Earth's athmosphere, most of them just not in interstellar space.

Answer (score 2):

Nuclear fusion: energy is produced by nuclear fusion of hydrogen nuclei into helium, no need for oxygen.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion